# Error log in Joomla K2

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

How to fix this error in error log ( Joomla K2 ) ?

```
href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 7 in /home/tesstr13/public_html/administrator/components/com_k2/lib/class.upload.php on line 2843
[12-Apr-2014 21:03:21 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Warning:  preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 7 in /home/tesstr13/public_html/administrator/components/com_k2/lib/class.upload.php on line 2870
[12-Apr-2014 21:03:21 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Warning:  preg_match() [<a href='function.preg-match'>function.preg-match</a>]: Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 7 in /home/tesstr13/public_html/administrator/components/com_k2/lib/class.upload.php on line 2915
```

Errors such as this several thousands.

Comment: contact the developers of K2

Comment: http://getk2.org/community

Comment: You might want to ensure you're using the latest k2 version, contact the devs as @Lodder said, and if you still can't get out of it tell us what administrator/components/com_k2/lib/class.upload.php on line 2843 and surroundings says